# jQuery on WordPress Theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a problem with the library jQuery for WordPress.

When I install the latest libraries there are problems with the display of a number of elements on the page.

This is because the default theme is jQuery 1.12.4 with the option Migrate 1.41.

Replacing the latest library allowed my script to work but caused a lot of things to stop working.

```
<Script type = "text / javascript">
$ (Function () {
$ ( "# Omnie-text"). Hide ();
   $ ( ". Omnie-menu"). Click (function () {
     $ ( "# Omnie-text"). SlideToggle ();
     $ ( "# Main-hero-section"). AddClass ("main-hero-switch-background");
   });
});
</ Script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why so many capitals and spaces? This works for me in 1.12.4:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#Omnie-text").hide();
   $(".Omnie-menu").click(function () {
     $("#Omnie-text").slideToggle();
     $("#Main-hero-section").addClass("main-hero-switch-background");
   });
});
</script>
```